# Tell notification server that application has been uninstalled

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I have an app that receives notification from GCM and client app can be automatically unregistered after it is uninstalled according to https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration#unregistration-and-unsubscription
But here in second step it is mentioned that my application/notification server is the one who informs the GCM that application has been uninstalled but as there is no event handling method during app is uninstalling procedure,then how will I inform my notification server that app has been uninstalled no notifications should be delievered now.

Comment: you're misunderstanding the docs I suggest you to read it more carefully. `8. The GCM returns a NotRegistered error message to the app server` GCM server notifies your server that is not registered and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

> how will I inform my notification server that app has been uninstalled no notifications should be delievered now.

You don't, Google does that for you.

Here is what it says

> 7. The app server sends a message to GCM.
> 8. The GCM returns a NotRegistered error message to the app server.
> 9. The app server should delete the registration token.

What is meant here is that the GCM service will take care of the unregistration on Google's side for you. After that happens, an attempt to send a push messages to the ID that was associated with the device will return a NotRegistered error. When that happens, your server will know the app was uninstalled.

There is no call from the android app to your server, it is handled via Google's service.

Comment: What message will Application server send to GCM?

Comment: @SwagDevelopers they mean a regular GCM push message

Comment: Ohkk got it.. the app is uninstalled and no msg should be delievered to this device is handled by gcm itself?

Comment: @SwagDevelopers yes the message will not be sent to the device and an error is returned to your server so your server knows that it should delete the token